# strange windows auth in iis, ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm making a personal management site only for me(using ASP.Net MVC, IIS8.0), so I want to use Windows authorization.

I turned on Windows authorization in IIS, so I can log on my web site on outside of my computer (like smartphone, both 4G network and WIFI LAN)

**BUT I can't log on my site in my computer**

actually, I can log on(automatically logs on) when I use url : *[http://localhost/]*.

but when I access via my own domain, ex. *[http://myowndomain.com]*, It shows a basic authorization form, When I submit the correct userId and password, it doesn't work and returns a 401 error. (401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.)

What's wrong with my settings?